# Segmented Control and Scroll View, Keeping Views in Memory

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uisegmentedcontrol

What I'm trying to achieve is basically a Instagram profile type screen.

I'm trying to recreate the segmented control section and what's beneath.

I thought about putting a container view containing the segmented control and a scroll view that switches between 3-4 views.

I saw many ways of implementing this, with or without a scroll view (the one I'm not really a fan of is the .ishidden method).

My main concern is **memory**. I don't know if it's better to keep them in memory or load them from scratch and also how to do that. Can you point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 1):

The instagram app doesn't do exactly what you described-- it looks like the only the first two options within the segmented control swap out the view underneath.  The last two navigate you to another view

You definitely want to load your views, assign them to `strong` properties, and then swap them out.

Add a Custom View in Interface Builder, that will be your container, and then  connect it to an `IBOutlet` in your controller.  You can instantiate your scroll views when the controller is instantiated, and then you can then add the scroll view as a subview to the container.  Then when the segmented control is pressed, you can remove that subview, and replace it with the new subview selected.

Instagram would arguably have some of the largest views, as far as memory allocation is concerned, to swap out (several images).  Yet you can tell that the scroll views are stored in memory because you can switch between them without reloading the images